# Whole function chain needs to be marked async in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a existing program and I need to call a 3rd party library function that provides only async operations.

Main -> f1() - f2() -> f3() -> f4()

f4 calls an async method of 3rd party. So f4 has to be marked async, then f3 has to be marked async and all the way up to main(). Is that correct understanding or not?

Comment: Close, but it should be `var result = Task.Run(async () => await TheAsyncMethod()).WaitAndUnwrapException();`

Comment: While there are methods to switch, it is _recommended_ to go "async all the way".

Comment: @JeremyThompson why wrap that into Task.Run? Third party method is already async.

Comment: @Fildor It's also a lot of unnecessary work for existing code bases. Plus, not everything needs to be asynchronous... IMO the entire async/await pattern should not even exist, it should have been handled by the CLR transparently...

Comment: I should add that `.WaitAndUnwrapException` is from Nito.AsyncEx... It is functionally equivalent to `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey My Point was that it is "only" _recommended_. Dealing with legacy code has _always_ its quirks and peculiarities.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey - and yet async/await is a common pattern that has been implemented across *multiple* languages. I trust multiple language designers have thought *hard* about this problem before they decided this was the best approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short version is "yes".

The longer version is that you technically *can* do a few things to avoid that, but: you'll be fighting the language and runtime at every step; it will certainly be *a lot more convenient* if you simply switch to `async`/`await` in that call-path. And yes, for this reason awaitable types are effectively "infectious" - it quickly spreads to more and more if your code. However, this is usually without much (if any) harm, and often has great advantages for scalability. A very benign infection.

Comment: What's the `async/await`s R number? ;)

Answer (score 1):

A way of thinking about async in c# is to think of it as virus: `f4` has been infected and it's only a matter of time before the whole program is async. The difference between a zombie virus and async is that:

1. there is no cure,
2. the main characters don't want to stop the virus but instead they encourage  you to get infected and
3. protection looks ugly and often suffers from hidden not-obvious bugs.

Can you stop the spread?

Prior to c# [7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history?WT.mc_id=ondotnet-c9-cxa#c-version-71) `main` couldn't be `async` and you'd have to write something like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MyAsyncWork().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

These days you can just

```
static async Task Main() // Or async Task<int> Main(string[] args) etc.
{
    return await MyAsyncWork();
}
```

The language designers acknowledged that async tends to go all the way to the entry point and they provided a way to not have to worry about the async/non-async jump.

However, there is no magic here and when we write `static async Task Main()` the compiler generates something like

```
private static void $GeneratedMain() => Main().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and that's what the 'real' main looks like.

Equipped with this knowledge you *could* make the async->non-async switch in `f4`. Doing this has risks and going async all the way often requires only a few minutes of changing method signatures (and optionally their names). Once done you can start leveraging all the benefits of asynchronous in more and more places in your code.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the situation that you're describing in your question:

```
async Task Main() { await F1(); }
private async Task F1() { await F2(); }
private async Task F2() { await F3(); }
private async Task F3() { await F4(); }
private async Task F4() { await ThirdParty.LibraryFunction(); }

public class ThirdParty
{
    public static Task LibraryFunction() => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
}
```

Do I need to `await` everything. No.

This works just fine:

```
async Task Main() { await F1(); }
private Task F1() => F2();
private Task F2() => F3();
private Task F3() => F4();
private Task F4() => ThirdParty.LibraryFunction();

public class ThirdParty
{
    public static Task LibraryFunction() => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
}
```

And what if `F4` need to use the result of the library function? Well that's when `ContinueWith` comes in to play.

```
private Task F4() =>
    ThirdParty
        .LibraryFunction()
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        });
```

Just remember that `async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar added on to the language to support TPL.

Comment: You can even avoid the `await` in `Main`, but: I strongly suggest *against* using `ContinueWith` here; this is absolutely an `await` scenario

Comment: @MarcGravell - Agreed, but the OP was asking if you had to. You don't, but you should.